# Using a condition instance with a lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

What happens when a condition is associated with a lock like this:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition();
```

An example would be the bounded buffer class such as [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

So when, for example, the methods notFull.await() and notFull.signal() are called, what is being waited on to be released/what is being signaled to other threads as now being free to use.

My assumption was that in this case these methods are checking/signaling the state of the lock, whether it's locked or unlocked.
So for example if lock.lock() was just called and then notFull.await() was called, this would lead the thread which called the notFull.await() method to be blocked/sent into the waiting queue.

Am I right with my conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--)

> The lock associated with this `Condition` is atomically released and the
>   current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and
>   lies dormant until one of four things happens:
>
> - **Some other thread invokes the signal method for this `Condition`** and the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened;
>     or
> - Some other thread invokes the `signalAll` method for this `Condition`; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread, and interruption of thread suspension is supported; or
> - A "spurious wakeup" occurs.

So something would need to call

```
notFull.signal();
```

or

```
notFull.signalAll();
```

or interrupt the waiting thread, or a spurious wake up would need to occur for the waiting thread to be made runnable again.

Comment: Thank you. My question was badly phrased but you helped point me in the right direction even though I had already read the documentation. Just goes to show that reading a thing twice never hurts. Cheers!

Comment: @OmarSharaki Consider clarifying your question.

Comment: I did. I hope it's more helpful to others now.

Comment: @OmarSharaki Ok, so that's the beauty of `Condition` objects. You can create multiple `Condition` objects from the same `Lock`, but by calling `signal()` on a `Condition` you'll only wake up threads waiting because they had called `await` on that same `Condition` object. From the documentation is linked and quoted, _Some other thread invokes the `signal` method for **this `Condition`**._

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like part of the implementation of a bounded, blocking queue (or other bounded, blocking pool-like class).  A producer that changes the state of the queue from not empty to empty by adding an item would call `notEmpty.notify()` so that a consumer that was waiting in a `notEmpty.await()` call could wake up and remove the new item from the queue.

Likewise, a consumer that changed the state from full to not full by removing an item would call `notFull.notify()` to awaken a producer that was blocked in a `notFull.await()` call.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.testjava;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
//=========== Task1 class prints odd =====
class TaskClass1 implements Runnable
{

    private Condition condition;
    private Lock lock;
    boolean exit = false;
    int i;
    TaskClass1(Condition condition,Lock lock)
    {
        this.condition = condition;
        this.lock = lock;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            lock.lock();
            for(i = 1;i<11;i++)
            {
                if(i%2 == 0)
                {
                    condition.signal();
                    condition.await();

                }
                if(i%2 != 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" == "+i);

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

}
//==== Task2 : prints even =======
class TaskClass2 implements Runnable
{

    private Condition condition;
    private Lock lock;
    boolean exit = false;
    TaskClass2(Condition condition,Lock lock)
    {
        this.condition = condition;
        this.lock = lock;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            lock.lock();
            for(i = 2;i<11;i++)

            {

                if(i%2 != 0)
                {
                    condition.signal();
                    condition.await();
                }
                if(i%2 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" == "+i);

                }

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            lock.unlock();

        }

    }

}
public class OddEven {

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        Future future1;
        Future future2;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        future1 = executorService.submit(new TaskClass1(condition,lock));
        future2 = executorService.submit(new TaskClass2(condition,lock));
        executorService.shutdown();


    }


}
```

Comment: You need to explain how your code dump answers the question.